# How do you calculate the time taken in a collision?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, collision, spring, estimation

For example a car with a known speed and mass crashes with a completely unyielding wall. The car has a crumple zone, (and you know the modulus of the crumple zone) so it doesn't stop immediately, but how can you calculate the time it takes for it to stop?

I've been reading a relevant article (Analytical approach for vehicle body structures behavior under crash at aspects of overloading and crumple zone length) but their equations are beyond me.

First question, had a hard time finding any help with this. Thanks!

The journal article in question:
[Analytical Approach for Vehicle Body Structures Behaviour Under Crash at Aspects of Overloading and Crumple Zone Length](https://sciendo.com/article/10.2478/ama-2023-0008)

Comment: Appreciated. That's why I was a little leery of linking it, but did notice it was CC.

Comment: There are multiple variables involved. If you know the stopping distance you can calculate the average impact  force using the work energy theorem. Then having  the average impact force, you can calculate the stopping time using the equation for impulse of force

Comment: See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/impulse.html#:~:text=The%20process%20of%20minimizing%20an,force%20by%20the%20same%20factor.

Answer (score 0):

The force of the impact can be found as follows:

$$F=\frac{-mv^{2}}{2d}$$

where $d$ is the amount by which the car crumples.

From there, it's a straight-forward application of kinematics to find the time it takes an object under constant acceleration to become stationary by taking:

$$t=\frac{-v}{a}$$

So put all together:

$$t=\frac{2d}{v}$$

Of course, this is **highly** idealized. A realistic car crash will have many complications involved with it that serve as abstractions from this solution. Despite that, this solution can be taken as a first order approximation for such circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the article you linked, time of the collision is given by formuli 19-23. From this:
$$t = \int_0^b \frac{db}{\sqrt{V_0^2 - \frac{2}{m} \int_0^b F(l) dl}} = G(b) - G(0),$$
you get $b(t) = G^{-1}(t)$. Then, you do $V = 0$ in 23 to get the time:
$$0 = V_0 + \int_0^t \frac{-F(b(t))}{m} dt.$$
We see that we need the real $F$. But the authors say "an exact reconstruction without referring to the approximated function relying only on the experimental dataset". So they have some values for $F$ and they have used it to calculate the integrals, but they haven't share the data set, so we cannot reproduced the figure 6b.

You can see that if $F(b) = kb$, then the collision time does not depend on initial velocity, $V_0$, as seen in figure 6a.